# Handling a return from Google Checkout

Tags: e-commerce, google-checkout

I need to capture server side a notification of a users payment. I've gone through a good majority of the documentation with no luck, but will go through it again. Is there a way to enable a "return to site" after they complete the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched `google checkout return url` and got http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/return-url-in-google-checkout-after-payment-t561.html

**veerlapallavi wrote...**

> There are 2 methods through which you
>   can provide the return URL.  1) Go to
>   your Google checkout account and Open
>   the settings. In the settings>>Profile
>   you can find a field with name "Public
>   business website:" provide your return
>   URL there.
>
> 2) The second method is , You can pass
>   the value to Google Checkout with the
>   HTML form as a hidden variable.
>
> `<input name="continue_shopping_url"
>   type="hidden"
>   value="http://www.yousite.com/payment_success.php">`
>
> OR
>
> Set a function as below 
>   SetContinueShoppingUrl("http://www.yousite.com/payment_success.php");
>   function SetContinueShoppingUrl($url)
>   {  $this->continue_shopping_url =
>   $url;  }

Hope that helps.

It looks like you can configure gcheckout to send you XML notifications, but I don't see how you can associate it with a particular order ID other than matching fields or something...

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html#new_order_notifications

Comment: Thank you! I seem to be weak on Google-Fu this week.

Comment: No worries! I'm hungry for SP (stack points) and random things I learn along the way :)